# Rollback Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Actually I jave a Job with several steps and two tasklets as follow:

```
@Bean
public Step stepItem() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepItem")
            .<Item, Item> chunk(10)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .processor(itemProcessor())
            .faultTolerant()
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step deleteAllItemStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("deleteAllItemStep")
            .tasklet(itemStepDeleteAllTasklet())
            .build();
}
```

Here my custom tasklet

```
public class ItemStepDeleteAllTasklet implements Tasklet{

private ItemRepository itemRepository;

public ItemStepDeleteAllTasklet(ItemRepository itemRepository) {
    this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
}

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    itemRepository.deleteAllInBatch();
    return null;
}
}
```

This is my configuration with the main job.

```
@Configuration
@Import({BatchItemConfiguration.class, BatchCriticalComponentConfiguration.class})
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private Step stepCriticalComponent;

@Autowired
private Step stepItem;

@Autowired
private Step deleteAllItemStep;

@Autowired
private Step deleteAllCriticalComponentStep;

@Bean
public Job importJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .start(deleteAllCriticalComponentStep)
            .next(deleteAllItemStep)
            .next(stepItem).next(stepCriticalComponent)
            .build();
}
```

}

Actually if a step (stepItem or stepCriticalComponent) fails,data that is deleted by the tasklet is gone and I cannot recover it. 
Is there a way to do a rollback on the entire Job or a rollback before a specific step/tasklet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of a rollback of an entire job or step within Spring Batch.  However, you can use a listener (`JobExecutionListener` or `StepExecutionListener`) to execute compensating logic to do a rollback by hand.